# Set Rewrite rules in Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to convert the following URL structure:

```
 http://www.example.com/forums/attachments/peasgai-emagazine/277230d1518788091-peasgai-emagazine-february-2018-peasgai-emagazine-feb-2018.pdf
```

to the following:

```
 https://www.example.com/community/attachments/277230/
```

So, basically, the first numbers till the `first letter (277230 d1518788091)` are an `ID` I have to convert to the new `URL` format.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^attachments/[^/]+/([0-9]+)d[0-9]+-.+$ /community/attachments/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Made the trick